# Wikipedia if statement dont work

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, mediawiki-templates

This is my Template:Test

```
id1: {{{#if: {{{id1}}} | {{{id1}}} | text1}}} <br>
id2: {{{#if: {{{id2}}} | {{{id2}}} | text2}}} <br>
id3: {{{#if: {{{id3}}} | {{{id3}}} | text3}}} <br>
id4: {{{#if: {{{id4}}} | {{{id4}}} }}} <br>
<br>
```

This is code of page TestPage using this template:

```
{{Test
| id1 = 123
| id2 = 
}}
```

The output of my TestPage (what user see) is:

```
id1: 123
id2:
id3: {{{id3}}}
id4: {{{id4}}}
```

I want the output to be:

```
id1: 123
id2: text2
id3: text3
id4:
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is this not outputing what I want?
Edit:
I am using mediawiki version mediawiki-1.30.0.

Comment: Unless you have a different version than what is used on Wikipedia, it has to be `{{#if`, not `{{{#if`.

Comment: You can also set a default so that if a value does not exist, the output is empty: `{{{id|DEFAULT}}}`, so for an empty default, use `{{{id|}}}`. This ensures that if `id` is not defined, the value which is output/used in the if-statement is empty.

Comment: I tried deleting one {. Now the output is id1: {{#if: 123 | 123 | text1}}.

{{{id|}}} and {{{id|DEFAULT}}} doesnt work either.

I am using mediawiki-1.30.0.

Comment: Which version of [ParserFunctions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions) do you use?

Comment: Can you replicate the examples given on [this help page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Parser_functions_in_templates)?

Answer (score 1):

When a parameter is not given (as for `id3` and `id4` of you example inclusion, `id2` is empty but given) the `{{{id3}}}` evaluates to the literal text `{{{id3}}}`. This is a truthy value in the `#if` condition.

Instead use `{{{id3|}}}`, which has a default value for "when not given" after the pipe, here it is empty - and treated as falsy in an `#if` condition. Consider

```
id1: {{{id1|text1}}}<br>
id2: {{{id2|text2}}}<br>
id3: {{{id3|text3}}}<br>
id4: {{{id4|}}}<br>
```

which for your inclusion would lead to the output

```
id1: 123
id2:
id3: text3
id4:
```

Since you are looking to get a default when the parameter is given but empty, you'd use

```
id1: {{#if: {{{id1|}}} | {{{id1}}} | text1}} <br>
id2: {{#if: {{{id2|}}} | {{{id2}}} | text2}} <br>
id3: {{#if: {{{id3|}}} | {{{id3}}} | text3}} <br>
id4: {{#if: {{{id4|}}} | {{{id4}}} }} <br>
```